# IE breaking page, and invalid markup validation

Tags: html, css, doctype, xhtml-1.0-strict

I have finished the layout and completed the webpage ([www.blisshair.com.au](http://www.blisshair.com.au)) but i have run into what I think is a major issue.

When building the webpage, I only used firefox to check the layout, and now I am kicking myself.

When loading the page in developer tools, IE 8 standards, browser IE 8, it loads pretty much perfect, except the header logo is twice as big as it should be.

When trying in I.E 7 standards, browser IE 7 it looks ok, however, IE browser 7, quirks mode, the page breaks down :

Have a clearfix issue just above the bottom footer, and the navigation (side) menu paddings are way off, the container div isn't centered (at least not on the index page, all other pages are..? )

I honestly have no idea whats going on, if someone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it,

Also, one last issue I was trying to correct and has left me scratching my head, I was trying to validate from W3C and got this error:

> Warning DOCTYPE Override in effect!
>
> The detected DOCTYPE Declaration
>   ""
>   has been suppressed and the DOCTYPE
>   for "XHTML 1.0 Transitional" inserted
>   instead, but even if no errors are
>   shown below the document will not be
>   Valid until you update it to reflect
>   this new DOCTYPE.

I thought "DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional" was correct?

If it helps, I have made a header and a footer html and attached them via include with php.
thanks again,

Nik.

EDIT : Problems resolved, thanks again to this site :)

Comment: I don't see it being related to PHP. Why the tag PHP?

Comment: I assumed the header and footer being included with PHP may have something to do with the DOCTYPE declaration.

Comment: Welcome to webpage development! IE is like the uncle that picks his nose at the table while kicking you in the shins; you just have to deal with it. If the strict doctype is being dumped for transitional, this probably means your markup does not valid as XHTML strict. Check it with this FF add-on: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/html-validator/

Comment: The issue is validation. And what validater sees is completely HTML.

Comment: Please click the outlined checkmark next to the answer you accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not much actually wrong with your site, so don't worry.

> When loading the page in developer
>   tools, IE 8 standards, browser IE 8,
>   it loads pretty much perfect, except
>   the header logo is twice as big as it
>   should be.

I don't see this in IE8 with IE8 Standards Mode, it looks the same as Firefox.

> When trying in I.E 7 standards,
>   browser IE 7 it looks ok

This is the same as using your site with Internet Explorer 7. It's good that your website works properly here, because it still has [some market share](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201004-201104).

> however, IE browser 7, quirks mode,
>   the page breaks down

Quirks Mode is basically emulating **IE5**. You do not have to worry about your website working in IE5. A visitor would only see your site in Quirks Mode if you had an invalid doctype that would not trigger Standards Mode.

Your doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

That's fine, and will most definitely trigger Standards Mode.

Your site does have [*some* validation errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.blisshair.com.au%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.2), but none of them are of the fatal variety.

Comment: wow, thanks so much, I was pulling my hair out for no reason.

Answer (score 2):

> however, IE browser 7, quirks mode, the page breaks down

Shrug, who cares? Quirks Mode is an emulator for IE 5.5, which no-one has used in years. You *might* today still worry about about what it looks like in IE6 Standards Mode, depending on who your audience are, but certainly nothing earlier than that. As long as your `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration is in place as it is now, no-one will ever see your page rendered in Quirks Mode.

> I thought "DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional" was correct?

Yeah, it is. The validator is just warning you that you've chosen to ignore the doctype on the page, in favour of explicitly using XHTML 1.0 Transitional (which is the same doctype as on the page anyway, but the warning doesn't notice that). Just leave the “document type” dropdown on the validator form on ‘(detect automatically)’ and the warning will go away.

Comment: wow, thanks so much, I was pulling my hair out for no reason.